# In what ways can I reduce bleed's duration?

Tags: path-of-exile

According to the wiki,

> Bleed's duration can be affected by following modifiers:
>
> - Ailment duration
> - Bleeding duration

My question is, what sources of reduced ailment duration and reduced bleeding duration exist out there?

I'm running a Flicker Strike Slayer, using the unique items [The Red Trail](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_Red_Trail) and [The Golden Rule](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/The_Golden_Rule) to maintain Frenzy charges, along with the Slayer node [Endless Hunger](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Endless_Hunger) to prevent the bleeds I constantly inflict on myself from killing me.  However, I've encountered a major issue:  Endless Hunger only protects me from bleed damage as long as I'm leeching, and I've found that my bleed procs are outliving my overleech stacks.  This is obviously a big deal, since the moment I lose my "immunity" to bleed from leeching, I instantly die.

The bleeds I inflict on myself via The Golden Rule are reflected versions of the ones I inflict on enemies, meaning that reductions to the duration of bleeds I inflict on enemies will also reduce the duration of the bleeds I inflict on myself.  However, I know of only one source so far -- the Unique gloves [Haemophilia](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Haemophilia). Are there any other sources of reduced bleed/ailment duration out there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Yoke of Suffering](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Yoke_of_Suffering) provides "30% reduced Duration of Ailments on Enemies", which works on bleed.  Although the mod specifies enemies, I believe it will work on bleeds you reflect onto yourself via The Golden Rule (since they are copies of the bleeds you inflict on enemies).

[Swift Affliction support](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Swift_Affliction_Support) will reduce the duration of your bleeds if you use it supporting the skill that inflicts the bleed, although giving up a support gem slot for this is a very expensive sacrifice to make.

Finally, anything that causes your bleeding or ailments to "deal Damage X% faster" will reduce its total duration, as clarified by Mark (GGG dev) in [this post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pathofexile/comments/be7kek/ailments_you_inflict_deal_damage_faster/eteenql/).  There are too many sources of this to easily list, but just going to the [wiki page for Bleeding](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Bleed) and ctrl+F'ing "faster" will find you most of them.

---

Aside from that direct answer to your question, I have to ask - why are you even running into this problem in the first place?  The base duration of bleed is 5 seconds.  The base max duration of a leech instance is *also* 5 seconds.  Unless you're somehow *increasing* the duration of your bleeds, or inflicting bleeds with hits that leech less than 10% of your life pool (which would surprise me, player damage is usually vastly larger than player life pools), your leech stacks and your bleeds should be expiring at the same time.

Why are your bleeds outlasting your leech stacks in the first place?

Comment: I am not sure to be honest. I double checked my skilltree looking for perhaps a notable that increased the ailment duration, but couldn't find anything. My issue was that there would always be a .5 - 1 second gap where my leech would end and I would take a rapid amount of bleed degen, sometimes so fast it was lethal, so I figured it had something to do with bleed duration

Comment: Interesting...I wonder if some of the leech stats end up shortening the total duration of your leech stacks by recovering the same life over less time or something like that.

Comment: You can chalk it up to me being completely stupid. Today I went to replace one of the older jewels I was using and found out that was the one causing the issues -- it has % chance to bleed + bleed duration. The whole time I was searching for my skill tree looking for a notable that was causing it, when it was the sleeper jewel :(

Answer (score 3):

There is no way know to me for players to reduce bleeding duration of bleeding debuffs apllied by enemies directly. The [Haemophilia gloves](https://pathofexile.gamepedia.com/Haemophilia) will **reduce bleeding duration on enemies** (there's a hint to it in their flavor text)

> A master artist takes his time when he's painting.
> Unfortunately, my kind doesn't often have that luxury.
>
> - Coralito, Brotherhood of Silence

However there is a solution to dealing with your problem of handling bleeding stacks and/or duration:

**Use flasks!**

Flasks should be used pretty much with a 100% uptime and having either an offensive or defensive flask with the suffix **"of staunching"** is almost necessary. This will give you bleeding immunity for the duration of the effect and remove all currently existing stacks.

Comment: Are you sure about this? If a bleed I inflict onto an enemy now has a reduced duration due to the effects of Haemophilia, shouldn't that same bleed afflict me with the same duration I've inflicted on the enemy?

Comment: Do also note that bleed removal is a lot different from bleed duration reduction -- the goal is to have less of a window where bleed can overlap the overleech duration.  I've heard rumors that "bleed deals damage x% faster" shortens the duration, as well as Crimson Dance shortening the duration. Can you attest to any of these?

Comment: @senpai Hm I'm not sure about how reflecting a bleed back would work. It probably would shorten the duration but I'm not sure about that. I'll adjust the answer though. I just wouldn't know about any way of lowering bleed durations of bleeds applied by enemies directly.

Comment: @senpai the flask thing is just a thing I've used on most of my builds since you're basically using flasks as abilities in the later stages of the game anyways.

Comment: And you're right for 99.9% of builds out there. It's just that for this particular question, Staunching flasks would probably be the worst option for me

Comment: @senpai For your questions in the comments here:  Reductions to bleed duration on enemies *do* reduce the duration of the copies you reflect onto yourself via The Golden Rule; "x% faster" *does* reduce the duration of bleeds (they do the same total damage, more per second but over less time); Crimson Dance *does not* reduce the duration of your bleeds (it doesn't interact with duration in any way).